# .removeClass not working, and preventing .addClass from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a hard time finding any information that helps with this issue. I've tried several other options that worked for other people on here, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have a div set up like this:

```
    <div class="dynamic-content">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is apply a CSS animation to .dynamic-content when .button is clicked, by adding a specific class, and then removing that animation by clicking .button again and removing the specific class.

Here is my jQuery:

```
    $(".button").on('click', function() {
        if ($(".dynamic-content").hasClass('open')) {
            $(".dynamic-content").removeClass('open'));
        } else {
            $(".dynamic-content").addClass('open'));
        }
    }
```

If I don't include the .removeClass() part, the addClass works perfectly. However, as soon as I put in the .removeClass, in the inspector, I can see .dynamic-content lighting up, as if targeted and acted on by JS, but nothing happens, not even .addClass is working.

Comment: How do you debug it??? Because there is obvious typo in your posted code so?!

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out! I think that was an issue with me retyping the code in here. I did, however, double-check my code to make sure I didn't have any extra braces.

Comment: Other issue could be because you have `.button` nested element and so event hanlder is fired twice on each click. Or you have any other click handler bound to any parent toggling this class again. What if you add: `$(".button").on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); /* rest of code*/ });`

Comment: Hey A. Wolff, as it turns out, I had overlooked the fact that I was calling my .js file twice. Once I fixed that, my issue ended up resolving. Thank you for your input, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have error in your code at line:

```
 $(".dynamic-content").removeClass('open'));
                                        //^Remove extra brace
```

Remove extra spaces and you are good to go.

You can also optimize your code by using `.toggleClass()`:

```
$(".button").on('click', function() {
   $(".dynamic-content").toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Hey Milind, I removed the extra brace, and switched to .toogleClass, but I'm still running into the same issue. The inspector shows the element flashing when I click on it, but it does nothing.

Comment: @BeardedWineGuy: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Comment: @MiliandAnantwar: I feel horrible, and I apologize for wasting your time; I went to grab my code again to plug into fiddle, and realize I was calling my .js file twice. I removed the second call for it, and it fixed everything.

Comment: @BeardedWineGuy: not a problem. glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$(".button").on('click', function() {
        if ($(".dynamic-content").hasClass('open')) {
            $(".dynamic-content").removeClass('open');
        } else {
            $(".dynamic-content").addClass('open');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the brace issue I validly had in the above code. I ended up realizing that I was calling my .js file twice, which is what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the conditional work? Because ".dynamic-content" is a class, jQuery will get the first one it finds. Maybe there's another one on the page, which plays with your condition?

Another thing that may happen, as people have said, is that your extra ")" is breaking your function.

Either way, I would try toggleClass instead, it does exactly what your condition does:

```
$(".button").on('click', function() {
    $(".dynamic-content").toggleClass("open")
}
```

If the class is there, it removes it, if not, it adds it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the brace issue I had there. I think it was an issue with transcribing my code in stackoverflow, but that was an issue. As it turned out, though, my biggest issue was my oversight in not realizing that I had called my .js file twice. Once I fixed that, my issue ended up resolving. I did however, switch over to the .toggleClass method.